# How to check if a window was instantiated from a window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

Is it possible to check if a window was opened from a `window.open()` with the new opened window itself. I only want the website I am opening to be display a specific context when opened from a `window.open()`. It is cross-origin. For example: if the URL is accessed and not opened from a `window.open()`, I want it to redirect elsewhere. I know this is possible from the parent window, but not sure if it can be done from the child window

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener). This will return a reference to the window that opened the current window or `null` if it is not opened by `open()`.

```
if (window.opener) {
    // Opened from another window
} else {
    // Not opened from another window
}
```

Comment: @Ryan Yes, it will.